# How are geocoder api results sorted?

Tags: here-api

When I try this below query for "Santa Cruz":

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=APP-ID&app_code=APP-CODDE&gen=9&searchtext=Santa+Cruz&countryfocus=USA

2 items are returned:

Santa Cruz, CA

Santa Cruz, NM

On what basis is the result ordered? Is it based on distance or some other parameter?(both these cities have the same relevant, match level & match quality).

Secondly, If I need the nearest "Santa Cruz" amongst these 2, is there any API to extract that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find nearest from your position or from any position, use Matrix routing.
Specify the position of reference in source, each of the position to test as destination. In one request, Matrix Routing will give you distance/time between source and each destination.

Check developer.here.com for developer’s guide

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder results are ordered by prominence. So in this case Santa Cruz in CA is searched for more often than Santa Cruz in NM.

You are asking for a distance, but what is the reference point? There is not much meaning in a distance from the middle of the "country focus" (=USA in this case) to the response locations.

Comment: Hi, reference point is the current location. Say if I want to find out how far is Santa Cruz(and am in NM), i would rather prefer to get Santa Cruz, NM's location. So I guess, in this case this has to be done by code i.e. from the JSON list, find out which Santa Cruz is in same state as my location and then use calculate route?

Comment: An edit for my comment above:  will try using matrix using suggested by DevBab below.